# Difference between Gopi Chandan & Vibhudhi

Tags: vedas, puranas, advaita, vaishnavism, sri-vaishnava

Can someone tell me the Differences between Gopi Chandan & Vibhudhi? Who wears which one?

Comment: Gopi chandan vaishanavas mark where as vibhudhhi saivaite mark.. it depends my primary deity is Vishnu so i wear urdva pundra and saivaite wear vibhuthi tri pundra. horizontally basically theres primary deity is shiva..

Comment: @PrasannaR, thank you for the comment. But I was asking like, Sri Vaishnavas wear the tilak in red/yellow. Thenkalai/Vadakalai. But some people, do not wear like that. They only wear the U portion (no tilak inbetween the U. Probably only a chandrabindu type inbetween the U) and that too not the same substance that the Sri Vaishanavas use. Any idea on what this is? Why is the reference or whom do they worship? I guess the people who sport the Gopi chandan do not tell that they are Sri Vaishanavas. They tell they are Smarthas. Any idea?

Comment: I Believe your question is termed in generic not specific to sri vaishnavas you change the question if yo happen to cross TN then all the markings are forming Gobi chandan

Comment: @PrasannaR, yes, In TN only I am asking. Certain people sport Gopi chandan. Are the madvas?

Comment: this marking of sri vaishanas may be specific to that community which is spread across india and majoritliy tamil speaking. but urdva pundra is generic vedic symbol for conducting vedic rites.. any homa, havana one should wear urdva pundra.. otherwise it become non vedic. even smartas can also wear urdhva pundra.. but the philosophy is dileuted.. Yes madhvas do gopichand it is available across dwaraka and virdhavan.. predominantly north indians wear gopichand only with u marking.. as you said they also believe the same its krishnas foot mark. and

Comment: also gopichandan had to dissolved from nirmalya of saligrama with lords foot mark separately.. now clearly its connection between lords foot and the head of devotee